# Unable to generate Url for the name 'index' in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I am having a little routing problem, here is my code in my controller :

```
...
else {
return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
}
...
```

And here is the message I am having :

```
 Unable to generate a URL for the named route "index" as such route does not exist.
```

And My routing file is :

```
front_signup:
  path:     /signup
  defaults: { _controller: FrontBundle:signup:inscription }
front_index:
  path:     /index
  defaults: { _controller: FrontBundle:index:acceuil }
front_login:
  path:     /login
  defaults: { _controller: FrontBundle:login:connection }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try: `$this->redirectToRoute('front_index');`

Comment: Worked! thank you friend!

Comment: Make it an answer @la

Comment: Tokeeen : i can not, because it is a comment not an answer! if he make it  as answer i would make it as answer with joy.